# Powershell - json File - select only first value

Tags: arrays, json, powershell

I've got this json file:

```
[
  {
      "group": [313, 312, 313, 311], 
      "group_name": ["example", "example", "example1"], 
      "status": ["not_available_time", "no_time"]
  }
]
```

And in Powershell I want the output to be:
**313, example, not_available_time**

So I always need just the **first value.**

I've tried this:

```
$responseJson = ConvertFrom-Json $response.Content

$group = $responseJson.group[0]
$name = $responseJson.group_name[0]
$status = $responseJson.status[0]
```

That works. But only if there is always more than one value.
For example: if `"group_name"` in the JSON file would only hold the value `"example"` (and not `["example", "example", "example1"]`) => the output would only be `"e"` instead of `"example"`. It takes not the first value, but only the *first letter* if there is only one value.

**How can I select the first value?**

BR and thanks!

Comment: Wrap them in array subexpression to ensure it's always the index 0 of an array => `@($responseJson.group)[0]` and `@($responseJson.group_name)[0]` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 safe methods to ensure you're always selecting the first **Value**, be it an *array*, a *scalar* or *null*:

- You can use the [array subexpression operator `@()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#array-subexpression-operator--), which will ensure that even if the value is [`$null`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-null?view=powershell-7.2) or [`[System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.internal.automationnull.value?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0#system-management-automation-internal-automationnull-value) the result **will always be an [array (`object[]`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array?view=net-6.0)**:

```sh
@([System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value).GetType().Name # => Object[]
@($null).GetType().Name # => Object[]
```

- As an alternative, [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2) with the `-First 1` argument, the difference is the returned object's Type remains the same:

```sh
(1 | Select-Object -First 1).GetType().Name        # => Int32
('a', 'b' | Select-Object -First 1).GetType().Name # => String
$null -eq ($null, $null | Select-Object -First 1)  # => True
```

---

Both alternatives are valid and depends on your use case which one fits your need better:

```sh
$json = @'
[
  {
      "group": [313, 312, 313, 311],
      "group_name": "single_element",
      "status": null
  }
]
'@ | ConvertFrom-Json

$json.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object {
    $arr = @($_.Value)[0]
    $slo = $_.Value | Select-Object -First 1

    [pscustomobject]@{
        'ArraySubExpression' = "[ {0}: $arr ]" -f $_.Name
        'Select-Object'      = "[ {0}: $slo ]" -f $_.Name
    }
}


ArraySubExpression             Select-Object
------------------             -------------
[ group: 313 ]                 [ group: 313 ]
[ group_name: single_element ] [ group_name: single_element ]
[ status:  ]                   [ status:  ]
```